# ¿Existe un adjetivo calificativo para expresar "que invita a la acción"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Estoy buscando un adjetivo calificativo para expresar *que invita a la acción*.

Yo pensé que la palabra precisa era ***proactivo***, pero no es así. Proactivo significa: *que tiene iniciativa y capacidad para anticiparse a problemas o necesidades futuras*. Sin embargo, yo necesito un término que promueva la ejecución de una acción inmediatamente.

Para explicar el contexto: en publicidad se habla de la fórmula AIDA, que se refiere a las cualidades que debe tener un anuncio: llamar la Atención, mantener el Interés, despertar el Deseo y Promover la Acción. Entonces quiero aplicar esta fórmula en un producto artístico. Quiero decir que dicho producto debe ser Atractivo, Interesante, Seductor y... Ese último adjetivo es el que me falta.

Comment: Interesante pregunta. De momento en el DLE solo he encontrado _[invitador](https://dle.rae.es/?id=M4WoOXH)_, "que invita". Igual podrías considerar _[tentador](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZU7aapF)_, podría funcionar dependiendo del contexto, el cual te animo a incluir en la pregunta si dispones de uno, así obtendrás mejores respuestas.

Comment: A mi lo único que se me ocurre es [apremiante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3IRm0FB) aunque creo que tiene más connotación de "obligar" que "invitar" a que se haga algo. Como dicen otros comentarios, sería bueno matizar ese "invitar".

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre con *incitador*.

Comment: Mis sugerencias: *alentador, estimulador*. "inductor" suele tener connotación negativa (que induce al delito).

Comment: Voté por cerrar por no dejar claro cómo quieres usar el término que solicitas.  Se me ocurren varias ideas: *dinámico, eficaz, persona de acción, iniciador, focalizado, dirigido, orientado a la acción, medidas de acción, proceso ágil.*  Depende mucho del contexto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, sirven muy bien y me encanta el término "tentador". Con respecto al contexto... en publicidad se habla de la fórmula AIDA, que se refiere a las cualidades que debe tener un anuncio: llamar la Atención, mantener el Interés, despertar el Deseo y Promover la Acción. Entonces quiero aplicar esta fórmula en un producto artístico. Quiero decir que dicho producto debe ser Atractivo, Interesante, Seductor y ...  Ese último adjetivo es el que me falta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: El término ***movilizante*** es muy comúnmente usado (en Argentina) y recién veo con sorpresa que no aparece registrad como adjetivo en el diccionario RAE (pese a que si existe el verbo **movilizar**)

movilizar, de móvil e -izar.


>1. tr. Poner en actividad o movimiento. U. t. c. prnl.
2. tr. Convocar, incorporar a filas, poner en pie de guerra tropas u otros elementos militares. U. t. en sent. fig.

Comment: En el mismo sentido se emplea ***movilizador***

Ver estos ejemplos de uso aqui https://es.glosbe.com/es/es/movilizador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como primera opción se me ocurre **provocador**:

> [**provocador, ra**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UUoDxk2)
>   `Del lat.`*`provocātor, -ōris`*`.`
>
> 1. adj. Que provoca, incita, estimula o excita.

Desde la página del DLE y pulsando en cada uno de esos cuatro verbos, podemos ver sus definiciones; destaco las que podrían aplicar:

> **provocar**
>   Buscar una reacción de enojo en alguien irritándolo o estimulándolo con palabras u obras.
>
> **incitar**
>   Inducir con fuerza a alguien a una acción.
>
> **estimular**
>   Hacer que alguien quiera hacer algo o hacerlo en mayor medida.
>
> **excitar**
>   Provocar o producir una reacción o una respuesta en algo o en alguien.

Según esas definiciones, ***provocador*** sería, en su sentido más positivo, algo o alguien que induce con fuerza a una persona a una acción, que hace que una persona quiera hacer algo (o hacerlo más), que provoca una reacción o respuesta en una persona.

De hecho, nos servirían también ***incitante***, ***estimulante*** y ***excitante***; quizá incluso *incitador* o *estimulador*.

Comment: Su aporte es realmente es bueno. Creo que me quedo con "provocador" y también me encanta "incitador". Son los términos que buscaba, Muchas gracias.

Comment: *Provocador* e *incitador* tienen otras connotaciones....

Answer (score 2):

Asiento otro adjetivo que encuentro especialmente apropiado en el sentido buscado de invitante a la acción (gracias @walen por la información del diccionario, arriba)

> ***movilizante***  de *movilizar*
>   (que convoca a la actividad, o pone en movimiento)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the exact same as *provocador*, but similar: in Colombia, when someone gives enough reason for something bad to happen to him, he is a ["*papayaso*"](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Papayaso.php). For example, someone slacking so much at work he ends up getting fired: he gave the reason to get fired, he is a *papayaso*.
And the verb is ["*dar papaya*"](https://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/dar%20papaya): walking in a bad part of the city wearing expensive stuff, putting yourself in a position of possibly getting robbed... that is *"dar papaya"*.
So it's like you invite to the action, but the action is something bad happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

El producto debe ser Atractivo, Interesante, Seductor y **Dynámico**.

Según el [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DnmOkpJ):

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la fuerza cuando produce movimiento.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la dinámica.
> 3. adj. Dicho de una persona: Notable por su energía y actividad.
> 4. f. Fís. Rama de la mecánica que trata de las leyes del movimiento en relación con las fuerzas que lo producen.
> 5. f. Sistema de fuerzas dirigidas a un fin.
> 6. f. Nivel de intensidad de una actividad.